# Assign reference of a non-existent property into a variable

Tags: javascript

This might be a stupid problem, but I have an object in which I wanted to store references of other functions/variables and later use them.

For example,

```
var obj = {
    keyA: {
        ref: window.objects.someAAA
    },
    keyB: {
        ref: window.objects.someBBB
    }
}
```

Here, when I set this object, `window.objects` is empty, so accessing those keys (`someAAA` and `someBBB`) will give `undefined`.

I know I was dumb when I first thought of assigning them like this and expecting their actual values after they're loaded, to be available via `obj.keyA` and `obj.keyB`. But obviously, they still contain `undefined`.

But is there a way to do that! I know if I set string instead of reference, I can `eval`, but any better solution?

Comment: You could have the values be functions that return the value of `window.objects.something` when you call them.

Comment: Do you use only javascript? Do you have any framework or libray such as jQuery?

Comment: I see, so no way of storing the reference. @CodeArtist, yes plain Js

Comment: The only way is the one that suggests @Kordi . If you had a library or framework you could use promises or callbacks. Callbacks is plain js but you have to restructure your code probably.

Comment: @CodeArtist O no, not that complicated, promises and stuff. I just wondered if I can assign a variable and then initialise later, but seems like its not possible.

Comment: @Салман With my code it works, its just a function but that shouldn't be a Problem or?

Comment: Naah, not a problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this should work

```
var obj = {
    keyA: {
        ref: function() { return window.objects.someAAA; }
    },
    keyB: {
        ref: function() { return window.objects.someBBB; }
    }
}
```

You can then access via

```
obj.keyA.ref()
```

**Test**

Add the code above then do

```
window['objects'] = {}; 
window['objects']['someAAA'] = 'Hallo';
obj.keyA.ref() // will Output 'Hallo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for such case:

```
var obj = {
    get keyA(){
       return (window['objects'])? window.objects.someAAA : null
    },
    get keyB() {
        return (window['objects'])? window.objects.someBBB : null
    }
}

// as now window.objects doesn't exists
console.log(obj.keyA);   // outputs "null"

window.objects = {'someAAA': "aaa-value", 'someBBB': "bbb-value"};

console.log(obj.keyA, obj.keyB);    // outputs "aaa-value" "bbb-value"
```